# Windows Server 2008 CALs for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, licensing, cal, cals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Our existing setup has 3 servers running on Windows Server 2008 and there are 75 users in the office. We have a total of 80 Windows Server 2008 user CALs for this.

We will be getting two new servers tomorrow and they will be loaded with Windows Server 2008 R2. Now, for compliance purpose, do we need to buy new Windows Server 2008 R2 user CALs for the existing users or the aforementioned Windows Server 2008 user CALs is good enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been no new CALs for Windows Server 2008 R2, the "old" ones can be used for accessing R2.

The [R2 License Guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/e/c/eecf5d44-9a88-43d8-afdb-d2ab82be035c/R2_License_Guide-ONLINE.pdf) explicitly states:

> Q: Can I use a Windows Server 2008 CAL to access a license for Windows
>   Server  2008 R2?
>   A: Yes, a Windows Server 2008 CAL can be used to
>   access Windows Server 2008 R2

the only exception is the "Remote Desktp Services CAL" which is nothing but a rename - it is [equivalent to the previously available "Terminal Services CAL" for Windows Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/07/27/windows-server-2008-r2-rds-and-windows-server-2008-ts-cal-compatibility.aspx).